# reading highest priority child from list in Firebase

Tags: priority-queue, firebase

I want to get the child with the highest priority in a Firebase's list, how do I do so without having to keep all the children at the client?

One way I could think of is to maintain a linked-list like data structure right into firebase:

```
head: 0
nodes:
  0: {next: 10}, priority=1
  10: {next: 4}, priority=23
  4: {next: 2}, priority=45
  2: {next: null}, priority=67
```

Then let say I update 0's priority to `46`, this triggers `on('child_moved')` event with `prevChildName=4`, then I'll update the head pointer and next pointers of nodes 0, 10 and 2 accordingly...

The other way is to keep a list of IDs in 1 place and update it accordingly:

```
list: "0, 10, 4, 2"
```

But as the list grows, each update will be very costly in term of bandwidth.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something, but this sounds like exactly what our [query](https://www.firebase.com/docs/queries.html) functions are meant for.  To get the item with the lowest priority number, you should be able to do:

```
ref.startAt().limit(1).once('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
  // childSnapshot is the item with the lowest priority number (item 0 in your example).
});
```

Comment: This is funny, FireBase is too easy to start with that I've only skimmed through the quick start pages and started building apps. I realize that I haven't read the Queries/Limits page yet! Sorry for my ignorance :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `limit()` and `endAt()` to get the highest priority. `endAt` with no arguments starts at the highest value.

```
var ref = FB.limit(2).endAt();
```

[Here's a fiddle showing it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/ZtZBg/4/). Fun fun fun! : )

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed example! Just a quick check: how is `limit(2).endAt()` different from `startAt().limit(1)`? EDIT: never mind, i got it, yours is to get 2 largest value, while the other is to get 1 smallest value. Thanks :)